# Reset headers as indexes and push it as a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
            Date 20191002-144129
0     Technician               J.
1         Jig SN              11
2  Assembly Type             10x
3    Assembly SN            2401
4  Exposure Cam3              49
```

I would like to reset the headers "Date" and "20191002-144129" to 0 1
and I guess that adding "Date" and "20191002-144129" as a new row is fairly straightforward. But I am struggling to reset the headers as indexes. Is there a way to simply "push" the headers as a new row?

Comment: Not sure what your final expectations are.  Does this work?  `df.T.reset_index().T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @piRSquared, this is a solution:

```
>>> dff = pd.DataFrame([{'Date': 'Tech', '201910': 'J.'}, {'Date': "Jig", '201910': 11}])
   Date 201910
0  Tech     J.
1   Jig     11

>>> dff.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
      0       1
0  Date  201910
1  Tech      J.
2   Jig      11
```

And you can rename the columns at once:

```
>>> dff.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True).rename({0: 'Col_A', 1: 'Col_B'}, axis='columns')
  Col_A   Col_B
0  Date  201910
1  Tech      J.
2   Jig      11
```

Anyway, I think that the **real origin** of your problem is that you're reading that data from a CSV file, without telling the reader that you have no header file at all.